# How to register Google OAuth bundle in Symfony 3.4 (PHP)

Tags: php, symfony, google-oauth, symfony-3.4

My aim is to incorporate Google OAuth into my Symfony 3.4.22 project.
I'm using Pimcore 5.6 which is built with Symfony as base.
But getting an error

I've tried various ways of registering the Google OAuth bundle - but have not found a solution.
Works fine on a Test Symfony 4 project.

Included these packages:

```
composer require knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle --ignore-platform-reqs
composer require league/oauth2-google --ignore-platform-reqs
```

And registered bundle:
app/AppKernel.php

```
$collection->addBundle(new KnpU\OAuth2ClientBundle\KnpUOAuth2ClientBundle, 0, ['test', 'prod', 'dev', 'staging']);
```

I'm not sure how to register the Google OAuth bundle.

With my Symfony v3.4 (PHP 7.1) project, I'm getting

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Class "AppBundle\Controller\GoogleController" used for service "AppBundle\Controller\GoogleController" cannot be found. in /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DependencyInjection/RegisterControllerArgumentLocatorsPass.php on line 68

Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Class "AppBundle\Controller\GoogleController" used for service "AppBundle\Controller\GoogleController" cannot be found. in /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DependencyInjection/RegisterControllerArgumentLocatorsPass.php on line 68
```

I expect the Google bundle to be registered - and struggling with this. Any help appreciated.

Comment: What makes you think that the given error message is related to any other bundle? It simply tells you that the given class could not be detected by the autoloader

Comment: Thanks Nico. Your question made me look at the problem differently. 

Resolved and I posted solution below.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved.

I had:

`class GoogleController extends FrontendController`

Should have had: `class GoogleController extends AbstractController`